# Notification window placement on Mavericks

Tags: macos, notifications

I would prefer my notifications to pup up in the middle of my screen so that I will be sure to notice them. Is there a Pref somewhere to do this? If not, is there an app equivalent to the previous iCal which will do this? Thanks.

Comment: According to this it is not possible http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71989/change-location-of-notification-center-alerts

Answer (score 2):

There is no settings in Notification Preferences to do that.

However, you can switch to Alerts, they will stay until you dismiss them.

Go to system preferences and open Notifications.

For each application you care, switch the notification to Alerts, so now you wont miss them on your screen.

Comment: I just posted the same answer as you. To get to this setting, go to: "System Preferences" > "Notifications".

Comment: it happens, just timing issue :) you probably type faster then me, as I was expanding my original answer.