# Change the location of Chrome notifications?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications

Chrome notifications are by default in the top right corner, and native notifications cover them.

It does not appear possible to change the location of native Notification Center alerts:
[Change location of macOS Notification Center alerts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71989/change-location-of-macos-notification-center-alerts)

Is there any way to change the location of Chrome notifications so that they are not covered by native notifications? I'm using MacOS Sierra.

The only workaround I've found so far is to [set Chrome to use native macOS notifications](https://www.macrumors.com/2016/04/06/chrome-native-os-x-notifications/), but these notifications doesn't hold all the information of the original Chrome notifications.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible right now, with Chrome's notifications or with [native macOS notifications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71989/change-location-of-notification-center-alerts) — they're stuck in the top right.

[This functionality used to exist on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GYDs.jpg), but isn't possible now, and there don't appear to be any plans for its implementation.